# UIImage View Not Rotating on Forced Landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, landscape, image-rotation

I am forcing the landScape of my ViewController to **.landscapeRight**. The ViewController is followed by a NavigationController with no set class(default).

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.myOrientation = .landscapeRight
```

However, the **UIImage** and the **navigationBar**(top of viewController) are not rotating to where I need it until i **physically rotate the screen.**

Im assuming this has to do with not having an assigned class to the Navigation Controller but I am not sure. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try going to the General tab on your app target (this is where you set your app's display name).  Scroll down to Deployment Info and try to mark the checkbox, Landscape Right

Answer (score 0):

This should really be done on your view controller. Have you tried it the usual way by setting the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` to `.landscapeRight`. Check [this out](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621438-preferredinterfaceorientationfor) for more info.